# SQL query taking Jan Month as 13 instead of 01

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( YEAR(MAX(my_date)) , '-', MONTH(MAX(my_date))+1 , '-', 01 ) , '%Y-%m-%d')
```

I am using this to extract date. I get following output:

```
Output        Data Entry till
2017-07-01    2017 June entry complete
2017-08-01    2017 July entry complete
```

But as soon as the data entry is done for 2017 December I get 2018-13-01 instead of 2018-01-01. I know it is because of the +1 I am adding in month value. I am unsure how do I loop it back to 01 after 12?

The value in csv file for my_date looks like 2017-01-06. It is in string format.

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: What is the value for `my_date` that isn't converting correctly? Also please don't tag thing as Microsoft SQL Server if this is for MySQL, they're not the same thing.

Comment: It is MySQL. Apologies for the wrong tag.

Comment: What are you trying to do here, and why are you calling `STR_TO_DATE` ?  Please show us sample input and output data.  Your current question is unclear.

Comment: Output is shown above. Input I have added in the edited version now. Please refer it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing date arithmetic on a string by adding 1 to the month. Instead, use the `DateAdd()` function.

```
SELECT date_add(STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( YEAR(MAX(my_date)) , '-', MONTH(MAX(my_date)) , '-', 01 ) , '%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Comment: But won't that change the values for other months also?